State Diagram in Finite State Machines
This question is in Grimaldi's book:
Let $I$ = $o$ = {0, 1}.
Construct a state diagram for a finite state machine that recognizes each occurrence of $1010$ in a string x $\in$ $I^*$. (Here overlapping is allowed.)
Here is the answer in the solution's manual:

My problem is when we are in state $s_3$ and we get a $1$ as an input, I think we should go to $s_1$ not $s_0$ because at $s_1$ we are remembering one $1$, but as you can see in the picture it goes to $s_0$.
what is it that I'm missing?
Thank you in advance for your help!
